# Rotating images and hidden menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I really like their navigation at [here](http://etchapps.com/), and I would mainly like to know how they turned the image so smoothly (I am assuming a jQuery plug-in, but the menu icons themselves don't turn), and how the menu is toggled on and off from clicking the image.

I tried to look at their source code, but the CSS is illegible.

P.S. Everything works in IE as well.

Comment: I've edited your question, becuase it was't question at first place!

Answer (score 1):

They are using [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

To turn the image they use:

```
.active .icon-menu {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

And to animate it they use:

```
.icon-menu {
    transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.785,0.135,0.15,0.86);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.785,0.135,0.15,0.86);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.785,0.135,0.15,0.86);
    -o-transition: -o-transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.785,0.135,0.15,0.86);
}
```

With these styles defined the animation is basically triggered by adding or removing the `.active` class on the corresponding `<a>` element.